# What is the format of PDF hash?

Tags: hash, pdf

When I use a tool like pdf2john.py from John The Ripper on an encrypted PDF, it gives me an output like:

```
testing1.pdf:$pdf$2*3*128*-1028*1*16*3ba51ab2b4f9210274ccb07b8da9ec59*32*aba227f510daac66c2d0c7d40684ed8000000000000000000000000000000000*32*f576b0bc14308d979692e71693089bc3f3295620a5b8af07e2e4d1145ec7d77b:::::./testing1.pdf
```

I would like to know what is the hash format used? I ask because most of the online rainbow table website doesn't accept PDF format, only MD5, SHA1 etc. I wonder if it is possible to extract the non-PDF specific part out to be used in those online rainbow table website?

Comment: Have you tried running john on the output? John will tell you what hash type it is trying.

Comment: Read the source code for the tool, pay attention to the imported modules.

Answer (score 1):

Hashcat lists a similar looking hash in their [example hashes](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes)

> 10500    PDF 1.4 - 1.6 (Acrobat 5 - 8)

```
$pdf$2*3*128*-1028*1*16*da42ee15d4b3e08fe5b9ecea0e02ad0f*32*c9b59d72c7c670c42eeb4fca1d2ca15000000000000000000000000000000000*32*c4ff3e868dc87604626c2b8c259297a14d58c6309c70b00afdfb1fbba10ee571
```

On John The Ripper it's also supported as you can see on this [walkthrough](https://attackdefense.com/challengedetailsnoauth?cid=717) and on [JTRs example hashes](https://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/john-the-ripper-hash-formats). The algorithm is there just called `pdf`.

I neither found information on extracting an MD5/SHA1 hash etc from the PDF hash nor rainbow tables for PDF. So it's probably not possible since the PDF hash algorithm may use salting and/or iterating.
So using Hashcat or John The Ripper is your only option.